# Prove that a metric space $S$ is disconnected iff $\exists$ a non empty subset $A$ of $S$ s.t. $A \neq S$ and $A$ is both open and closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Prove that a metric space $S$ is disconnected iff $\exists$ a non empty subset $A$ of $S$ s.t. $A \neq S$ and $A$ is both open and closed.

Below is my proof. Any input would be appreciated. I'm not totally convinced I have the correct notation for the "if" portion ...

$\Leftarrow$ if: $\qquad \quad$ Assume $S$ is disconnected and $U$ and $V$ form $A \subset S$.

$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ Since $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cup V = A$, we know $V = A \setminus U$. And since $U$ is open, $V$ is 
$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ closed.

$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ Since $U \neq \emptyset$, $V \neq A \Rightarrow A \neq S$.

$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ Thus, $A$ is a nonempty subset of $S$ that is both open and closed.

$\Rightarrow$ only if: $\quad \ $ Assume $A \neq S$ and $A$ is nonempty, open and closed.

$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ Since $A$ is closed, $S\setminus A$ is open.

$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ Since $ A < S , S \setminus A \neq \emptyset$

$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ So, $(S \setminus A) \cup A = S$ and $(S \setminus A) \cup A = S$

$\qquad \quad \quad \quad$ Thus, $S$ is disconnected

Comment: What's your definition of connected metric space? What do you mean when you say “$U$ and $V$ form $A$”?

Comment: You mix up "if" and "only if". The symbol for "if" is "$\Leftarrow$".

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos A set $S$ is connected iff it is not disconnected. A set $E \subset S$ is said to be disconnected iff there are disjoint, non empty subsets $A, B$ of $E$ s.t. $E = A \cup B$.

Comment: @c87 My guess is that the word “open” is missing there.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos from the definition or the proof?

Comment: @c87 From the definition.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I did miss that portion when I recited from memory. The definition my professor gave was "A set $S$ is connected iff it is not disconnected. A set $E \subset S$ is said to be disconnected iff there are disjoint, non empty subsets $A, B$ of $E$ that are open in $E$ and s.t. $E = A \cup B$".